# Закрытый статический член класса

Tags: ооп, c++

Здравствуйте, народ!
Собственно ищу ответ на вопрос, который однажды поставил меня в тупик и на который пока не нашел обьективного ответа, а именнно в каких ситуациях может понадобится наличие закрытого статического метода класса?

Comment: И хотя,  @fori1ton уже рассмотрел в своем ответе несколько вариантов, все же уточните, что именно Вы имеете в виду -- метод (функцию) или поле (переменную)?

Comment: вопрос о закрытом статическом методе (функции) класса.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вот несколько идей навскидку:

1. Логгер, собирающий сообщения только от экземпляров конкретного класса
2. Просто вспомогательный метод, который вызывается из другого статического метода класса
3. Счётчик созданных экземпляров класса
4. Семафор или мьютекс, синхронизирующий доступ к методам класса (сомнительно с архитектурной точки зрения, но всё же применимо)

Последние два пункта сокрее относятся к скрытым статическим полям, а не методам, но их можно реализовать и так. Вообще, все пункты, кроме второго, сомнительны, но это всё, что я смог придумать.

Answer (score 3):

Да, снаружи этот метод нельзя будет использовать. Но сам класс сможет вызывать этот метод.

Обычно статики используют для каких-то вспомогательных алгоритмов, которым не требуется доступ к данным объекта.

Но здесь есть один резон. В статический метод не передавается this, и теоретически это может быть немного быстрее, чем обычный приватный метод.

Answer (score 1):

Статические методы могут использовать только статические члены класса. К закрытому статическому методу не будет доступа из внешнего мира. Напоминатель программисту о том что он не сможет добраться к обыкновенным членам класса Через этот метод который он может использовать только в закрытой области. Другими словами, этот метод используешь только для статических членов класса в закрытой области. Пример использования : Обыкновенный счётчик который должен существовать на протяжении всей работы программы изменять данные которого можно только с помощью такого метода если члены класса в закрытой статической области. Соответственно этим методом могут пользоваться только сам класс и его друзья.